# Why isn't this glob working for a Rake FileList for my server?

Tags: ruby, file, rake, glob

How come I get an empty filelist from:

```
  files = FileList.new("#{DEPLOYMENT_PATH}\**\*")
```

Where DEPLOYMENT_PATH is `\\myserver\anndsomepath`

How to get a filelist from a server like this? Is this an issue of Ruby/Rake?

**UPDATE**:

I tried:

```
  files = FileList.new("#{DEPLOYMENT_PATH}\\**\\*") 
  files = Dir.glob("#{DEPLOYMENT_PATH}\\**\\*") 
  files = Dir.glob("#{DEPLOYMENT_PATH}\**\*")
```

**UPDATE** AGAIN: It works if I put server as:

```
 //myserver/andsomepath
```

and get files like this:

```
  files = FileList.new("#{DEPLOYMENT_PATH}/**/*")
```

Comment: Does it help if you escape your `DEPLOYMENT_PATH` slashes: `\\\\myserver\\anndsomepath`

Comment: "Ruby filelist is driving me nuts" is not a very good question title - we're not qualified psychologists.

Comment: The "issue" isn't with Ruby or Rake. The "issue" is with Windows doing things backwards from the rest of the world. Ruby *works* on Windows, but it's designed (thank god) from a *nix perspective.

Comment: Also, the backslash is use for escaping in interpolated strings. i.e.,  if you had a directory called `"C:\somedir\test\batch"`, the Ruby interpreter would see:
`C: omedir    esbatch`

Comment: @JasonLewis: What's "the rest of the world"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The majority of modern OSes that aren't produced in Redmond, e.g. BSD, Linux, OS X, Solaris, etc. I was being a little snarky. I try to keep it to a minimum on SE sites, but sometimes it comes out.

Comment: @JasonLewis: They're all Unix based OSes.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby' `File.join` is designed to be your helper when dealing with file paths, by building them in a system-independent way:

```
File.join('a','b','c')
=> "a/b/c"
```

So:

```
DEPLOYMENT_PATH = File.join('', 'myserver', 'andsomepath')
=> "/myserver/andsomepath"
```

Ruby determines the file path separator by sensing the OS, and is supposed to automatically supply the right value. On Windows XP, Linux and Mac OS it is:

```
File::SEPARATOR
=> "/"

File.join(DEPLOYMENT_PATH, '**', '*')
=> "/myserver/andsomepath/**/*"
```

While you can ignore the helper, it is there to make your life easier. Because you are working against a server, you might want to look into `File::ALT_SEPARATOR`, or just reassigning to `SEPARATOR` and ignore the warning, letting Ruby do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you do

```
Dir.glob("#{DEPLOYMENT_PATH}\**\*")
```

**Edit:** I think Ruby prefers you doing Unix-style slashes, even when you're on Windows. I assume the rationale is that it's better for the same code to work on both Unix and Windows, even if it looks weird on Windows.

**tl;dr**: If it works with `/` but not with `\`, then use what works.

Comment: @icn: Then there's probably something wrong with your string, rather than with FileList.

Comment: @RyanBigg: Teaching someone how to fish isn't an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Because:

```
 > "\*" == "*"
 => true
```

Use `"\\**\\*"` instead.

Comment: tried with   files = FileList.new("#{DEPLOYMENT_PATH}\\\\**\\\\*") , not working